# How to add attachments in Sendgrid Django

Tags: python, django, string, email, sendgrid

I'm trying to figure out how to add attachments to my email I am sending through sendgrid. I have an .xlsx file in the same directory however it won't get attached. I currently have my code like this:

```
    with open(f'name-{filenumber}.xlsx', 'rb') as fd:
        encoded = base64.b64encode(fd.read())

    attachment = Attachment()

    attachment.content = (encoded, 'utf-8')


    attachment.filename = f'name-{filenumber}.xlsx'
    
    message = Mail(
    from_email='email.@email.com',
    to_emails= os.getenv("RECIPIENT_EMAIL"),
    subject='Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
    html_content='<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Python</strong>')
    message.add_attachment(attachment)

    try:
        sg = SendGridAPIClient('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
        response = sg.send(message)
        print(response.status_code)
        print(response.body)
        print(response.headers)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message)
```

But I keep getting this error  `AttributeError: 'BadRequestsError' object has no attribute 'message'`

Along with this:

````
python_http_client.exceptions.BadRequestsError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request```
````

Comment: No it does not, I've read that post and I get the same error

Comment: first errpr `attribute error` is because in `e.message` e dont have `message` as attribute, you can change to to `print(str(e))` and for second one you need to see for which sendgrid version you are using the correct api or right format or not

Comment: I"m using sendgrid v6 and the code I've written is following their documentation

Comment: try to follow this https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/main/use_cases/attachment.md , add a full file name with path and see what you got